# How to Ignore Exceptions and Continue for loop from starting

Tags: java, exception, connection

hello guys i am trying to print title from a set of urls in an string array by for loop, while printing, in some cases a connection cannot be made and raising an exception which is stopping all the remaining elements....

i am using this code to print, can some one help me to ignore the exceptions and continue with the loop with another element from the string array...

```
for (int f = 0; f < fin.length; f++) //fin be string array of urls
{
Document finaldoc = Jsoup.connect(fin[f]).get();
out.println(finaldoc.title());
}
```

one of the exception is

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need a `try{ } catch { }`

```
for (int f = 0; f < fin.length; f++) //fin be string array of urls
{
    try {
        Document finaldoc = Jsoup.connect(fin[f]).get();
        out.println(finaldoc.title());
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException exception) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Obviously this is not good practice as it does not resolve or even handle the error, but this is how you would continue iterating through the loop.

Comment: `break`... he wants to continue the loop, not leave it. Also, this is fine practice. Maybe you want to see if the urls are real and are expecting a timeout under normal conditions: Your comment is wrong too

Comment: Yes, it will essentially ignore the exception.

Comment: i think 'continue' statement  is not required, is it right?

Comment: @syed99 It is not; I was just using it as an example of "something" to do in the catch block.  You can handle it however you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide an empty catch:

```
   for (int f = 0; f < fin.length; f++) //fin be string array of urls
   {
      try{
       Document finaldoc = Jsoup.connect(fin[f]).get();
       out.println(finaldoc.title());
      } catch(Exception e){}
   }
```

Comment: @KingAslan instead of ask if it will continue or not, try the code by yourself

Comment: thank you....for your suggestion.....but i am in a situation that i don't have time to try it by myself....

Comment: I would try this answer

Answer (score 0):

You need a while loop rather than a for loop. Then you can catch the exception and keep going. This will continue the loop while handling the exception in the manner of your choosing. Of course, a for with the continue in the exception handler will do the same as in the accepted answer. Oops!

```
int[] myArray = {1,2,3,4,5,4,2,3};
    int index = 0;

    while(index < myArray.length) {

        try {
            if(myArray[index] == 4) {
                throw new Exception();
            } else {
                System.out.println(myArray[index]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        index++;
    }
```